# Lipschitz condition for open sets

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I found the notion of "a bounded open set satisfying the Lipschitz condition" in a paper. Could anyone explain me how to apply Lips. condit. to sets??

Comment: The boundary of the set, can be written as a finite union of sets, which are graphs of Lipschitz functions.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reasonable meaning is the boundary of this open set is locally the level set (equivalently the graph) of a Lipschitz map.

For example, the interior of a polygon or a polyhedron is one such domain.